# Download zip file using java11 HttpClient.sendAsync()

Tags: java, zip, httprequest, github-api

I'm trying to download a zip file through a java program using GitHub API.

The program I'm using is the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // create client
        HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();

        // create request
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(URI.create("https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/zipball/:ref")).build();

        // use the client to send the asynchronous request
        InputStream is = client.sendAsync(request, BodyHandlers.ofInputStream())
                .thenApply(HttpResponse::body).join();
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("outputZipFile.zip");
            copy(is,out,1024);
            out.close();
        }catch(Exception e) {}
        
        
        
    }

    private static void copy(InputStream is, FileOutputStream out, int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        byte[] buf = new byte[i];
        try {
            int n = is.read(buf);
            while(n>=0) {
                out.write(buf,0,n);
                n=is.read(buf);
            }
            out.flush();
        }catch(IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println(ioe.getStackTrace());
        }
        
    }
```

When I try to run this I get empty body so the output file will be empty as well.
I noticed that using HttpURLConnection insted of Java11 HttpClient makes it work but I'd prefer to use this Java11 feature in order to send asynchronous requests.

I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

**EDIT**: The HttpURLConnection code I'm using at the moment is the following:

```
private void downloadVersion(String sha, String outputDestination) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL( getDownloadQuery(sha) );
                
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                if(authToken!=null) 
                    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + authToken) ;
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                
                InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
    
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outputDestination);
                copy(in, out, 1024);
                out.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {}
            
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your url (when set to correct github repos) may be returning redirect status 302. To make HTTP client follow redirects replace `HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient()` with use of `HttpClient.newBuilder()`. You can also simplify your code with try with resources and making use of `InputStream.transferTo`:

```
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder().followRedirects(Redirect.ALWAYS).build();

URI uri = URI.create("https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/zipball/:ref");
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(uri).build();

// use the client to send the asynchronous request
InputStream is = client.sendAsync(request, BodyHandlers.ofInputStream())
        .thenApply(HttpResponse::body).join();
try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("outputZipFile.zip")) {
    is.transferTo(out);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the simplification you suggested. I think the url is correct: it works from browser and works using HttpURLConnection (which is the solution I'm usign at the moment) Should I post the code I'm using right now?

Comment: Yes, it is worth adding your HttpURLConnection code as you may have additional setup which is missed out of your HttpClient version.

Comment: Okay I edited my question and added that part of code.

Comment: See my edit on following redirects, and you may need to use `HttpRequest.newBuilder().header("Authorization", ...)`

Comment: Okay, thank you. I'll try ASAP and let you know.

Comment: `Files.copy` would be shorter than `FileOutputStream`